# Weyl tensor of a Riemannian metric $g$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Does Weyl tensor of a Riemannian metric $g$ give information about the conformally-flatness of $g$?

Comment: In general, it’s not a good idea to edit and change your question after it has been answered. Instead, you might want to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

In dimensions greater than 3, the Weyl tensor gives the obstruction for a metric from being conformal to a flat metric. In other words, the tensor vanishes if and only if the metric is locally conformally flat. In three dimensions, there is a different tensor known as the Cotton tensor which plays the same role.

The Weyl tensor is the totally trace-free part of the Riemann curvature tensor, so at each point you can consider its largest/smallest eigenvalues or the sum of the eigenvalues squared (when viewing the tensor as a map of two forms) to get some notion of its size.